# Django web app error. Login_check() takes exactly 1 argument

Tags: python, django

So this is the view :

```
def login_check(request):
username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
    if user.is_active:
        login(request,user)
        return render(request,'authen/match.html')
    else:
        return render(request,'authen/notmatch_2.html')
else:
     return render(request,'authen/notmatch.html')
```

This is what should happen when I press the login button but it says that login_check() takes exactly 1 argument.

urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^register/', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^registered/', views.registered, name='registered'),
    url(r'^check/', views.login_check(), name='login_check'),
```

]

and the template is something really basic it has just one tag with the text "You are registered"

Comment: `urls.py` and your template will probably help decipher the issue.

Comment: Now you can see the urls.py file.

Answer (score 3):

i believe you should not call login_check() in the urls.py

try this

`url(r'^check/', views.login_check, name='login_check')`